# coremlc: Error: compiler error: generic_reshape_kernel: Invalid bottom shape (64 8 -2 1 1) for reshape to (4096 -1 1 1 1)

Tags: ios, swift, coreml, conv-neural-network, coremltools

I have converted my CNN keras model to .mlmodel to be deployed on CoreML mobile application but I'm getting this error message:

```
coremlc: Error: compiler error: Espresso exception: "Invalid 
argument":generic_reshape_kernel: Invalid bottom shape (64 8 -2 1 1) for 
reshape to (4096 -1 1 1 1)Command CoreMLModelCompile failed with a nonzero 
exit code
```

This is the only error message I get when running the app.
What is the source of this error and how can I fix it?

Any help would be appreciated, Thank you.

This is the .mlmodel details:
[mlmodel details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTNeQ.jpg)

Comment: Maybe the input size is too small? The -2 in the bottom shape is very suspicious. Please include the actual Keras model definition in your question; without this it is impossible to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Thank you for responding I will send you the model.

Comment: did you fixed it? I have the same problem @ABH

Comment: Yes, the problem was in both my keras model and the conversion code. Firstly, the keras model was written using both keras and Tensorflow libraries which was unnecessary in my case and caused the above issue, so I switched my code to run on keras modules/ functions only. Secondly, in my CoreML conversion code, I used Tensorflow to load my keras model which ended up missing with the dimensions due to incompatibility. Therefore, the solution was to stick to one model in creation and conversion, which in my case was keras model.

Comment: Thank you man for your answer,  I'll try and let you know if this works! I mixed keras nad tf statements too so this might be the problem!

Comment: could you answer your own question with a code sample of the model and conversion class?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I fixed the issue and created a CNN keras model and then converted it into MLModel

1- import keras and use keras stand-alone modules/functions/etc.

For example, instead of this..

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
```

Do this..

```
import keras
from keras import datasets, layers, models
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
```

2- Be consistent and choose the keras converter to match your already created keras model

For example..

```
import coremltools

output_labels = []
model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert('cnn_keras_model.h5',
                                             input_names=['images'],
                                             output_names=['output'],
                                             class_labels=output_labels,
                                             image_input_names='image')

model.save('converted_cnn_keras_model.mlmodel')
```